# Laravel: ReflectionException in Route.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.3 and have this in the web.php route file

```
Route::get('article/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@articles');

Route::get('contact/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@callUs');
```

and on the WebsiteController.php file I have these 2 fundtions

```
public function articles($key) {

        return 'article page';

    }

public function callUs($key) {

        return 'contact page';

 }
```

The problem is that for article (domain.com/articles/testing) it is showing the return text correctly but when I try the contact page (domain.com/contact/testing) I get the error:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 333:
Method App\Http\Controllers\Website\WebsiteController::callUs() does not exist
```

Both route are pointing to the same controller file and both functions as on the same WebsiteController.php file, but one works the other doesn't.

And if I change

```
Route::get('contact/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@callUs');
```

to

```
Route::get('contact/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@articles');
```

I works without any error. Any idea what went wrong here?

II works without any error. Any idea what went wrong here?

UPDATE:

WebsiteController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Website;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class WebsiteController extends Controller {

public function articles($key) {

    return 'article page';
}

public function contact($contactKey) {

    return 'contact page';
}

}
```

web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('articles/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@articles');
Route::get('/contact/{key}', 'Website\WebsiteController@callUs');
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the full controller code (with namespace and extends, etc.)? Thanks

Comment: Please show full your routes.php file content.

Comment: ... and the path to the controller class file

Comment: Set route like this Route::get('/contact/{key}', 'WebsiteController@callUs');

Comment: updated with the full content of both files as requested

Comment: well.... as you can see in the 'full contents' of your files,  the website controller in fact does not have a function called callUs() .... only articles() and contact() ...